# Processing bat and ball game on vertical axis

Tags: processing

This is the code I have at the moment but I want to put the bat on the y  axis and have it move up and down vertically rather than horizontally, and have the ball bounce in a left to right motion rather than up and down.  Help is needed quickly.  Thanks.

```java
int x=250; // Horizontal position of ball
int direction_x=2; // Change in horizontal position each time draw() executed
int y=150; // Vertical position of ball
int direction_y=2; // Change in horizontal position each time draw() executed
int lives=3;
int score=0;

void setup()
{
    size(400,400); // Create a window 400x400 pixels
}
void draw()
{
    background(255,255,255); // Clear screen to white
    fill(0,255,0); // Set fill colour to blue
    rect(mouseY-60,380,120,20); // Position rectangle using mouse

    fill(0,0,255);
    ellipse(x,y,20,20); // Draw blue disk centered on x,y diameter 20
    x=x+direction_x; // Update position
    if(x<10) direction_x=-direction_x; // Reverse direction if hit boundary
    if(x>(width-10)) direction_x=-direction_x;

    y=y+direction_y;
    if(y<10) direction_y=-direction_y;
    // if(y>(height-10)) direction_y=-direction_y;

    if(y>(height-10)) // If ball bits bottom of screen then miss..
    {
        direction_y=-direction_y; // Bounce
        lives--; // Reduce lives by one
        if(lives==0) exit(); // If lives is zero then quit
    }

    if((y>(height-30))&&(abs(mouseX-x)<60)) // If ball has bit paddle then..
    {
        direction_y=-direction_y; // Bounce
        score++; // Increase score by one
    }

    textSize(32);
    fill(0,0,255);
    text(score, 10, 30); // Display score
    text(lives,width-30, 30); // Display lives
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since help is needed quickly, you'll have better luck if you ask a specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type question. It's hard to help with general "how do I do this" type questions, other than to offer general tips.

That being said, there are two main approaches that I can think of:

**Option One:** Break your problem down into smaller steps. Start with a **blank sketch** and get **just the paddle** working how you want it to. Then try adding the ball. After that's working, then try adding game logic. This is the better option here.

**Option Two:** Since you seem to almost have this working going up and down, you **could** just rotate everything 90 degrees by using the `rotate()` function. This is a bit of a hack though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Kevin, got it working at last, turns out I just had to change co-ordinates of the paddle from  (mouseX,0,0,0) to (0, mouseY,0,0) and needed to add in an additional line of code to change the axis parameters.  I was doing my age old trick of over complicating things.

```
    int x=250; // Horizontal position of ball
    int direction_x=2; // Change in horizontal position each time draw() executed
    int y=150; // Vertical position of ball
    int direction_y=2; // Change in horizontal position each time dra) executed
    int lives=3;
    int score=0;
    void setup()
    {
     size(400,400); // Create a window 400x400 pixels
    }
    void draw()
    {
    background(255,255,255); // Clear screen to white
    fill(0,255,0); // Set fill colour to blue
    rect(0,mouseY-60,20,120); // Position rectangle using mouse

    fill(0,0,255);
    ellipse(x,y,20,20); // Draw blue disk centered on x,y diameter 20
    x=x+direction_x; // Update position
    if(x<10) direction_x=-direction_x; // Reverse direction if hit boundary
    if(x>(width-10)) direction_x=-direction_x;

    y=y+direction_y;
    if(y<10) direction_y=-direction_y;
    // if(y>(height-10)) direction_y=-direction_y;

    if(y>(height-10)) // If ball bits bottom of screen then miss..
    {
    direction_y=-direction_y; // Bounce
    lives--; // Reduce lives by one
    if(lives==0) exit(); // If lives is zero then quit
    }

    if(x<10)
    {
    direction_x=-direction_x; // Bounce
    x=30; // Force x to beyond the paddle on a restart
    lives--; // Reduce lives by one
    if(lives==0) exit(); // If lives is zero then quit
    }

    if((x<30)&&(abs(mouseY-y)<60)) // If ball has bit paddle then..
    {
    direction_x=-direction_x; // Bounce
    score++; // Increase score by one
    }

    textSize(32);
    fill(0,0,255);
    text(score, 10, 30); // Display score
    text(lives,width-30, 30); // Display lives
   }
```